# Laravel Route Redirect to home while route is defined correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel routing. Been searching for a half day but do not get any solution. This is really weird since some routes are not working and Here is the snippet of the route:list.

```
GET|HEAD  / .......................................................................... home › HomeController@index
  POST      _ignition/execute-solution ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController
  GET|HEAD  _ignition/health-check ........... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST      _ignition/update-config ........ ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  POST      api/image/upload ............................................................... UploadController@upload
  POST      api/invoice/approve/{invoice} ...................................... Dashboard\InvoiceController@approve
  PUT       api/pagemeta .......................................................... Shared\PageMetaController@update
  POST      api/post ................................................................ ListingDataController@storeApi
  GET|HEAD  api/test/{listing} ..................................................................................... 
  GET|HEAD  api/user ............................................................................................... 
  GET|HEAD  cari ....................................................................... FilterController@FilterPage
  GET|HEAD  confirm-password ............................ password.confirm › Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@show
  POST      confirm-password .............................................. Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController@store
  GET|HEAD  contact ........................................................................................ contact
  GET|HEAD  dashboard ........................................... dashboard.index › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Dashboard
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/coin ....................................... dashboard.coin › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Coin\Coin
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/coin/topup ...................... dashboard.coin.topup › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Coin\CoinTopUp
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/invoice ......................... dashboard.invoice › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Invoice\MyInvoice
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/invoice/history .... dashboard.invoice.history › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Invoice\InvoiceHistory
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/listing ........................... dashboard.listing › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Listing\Listing
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/listing/add ........................ dashboard.listing.add › App\Livewire\Dashboard\ListingAdd
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/listing/add/{category} dashboard.listing.add.category › App\Livewire\Dashboard\ListingAddCate…
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/listing/edit/{listing} ... dashboard.listing.edit › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Listing\ListingEdit
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/listing/statistic ................................................ dashboard.listing.statistic
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/membership ............. dashboard.membership › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Membership\MyMembership
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/membership/buy .... dashboard.membership.buy › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Membership\MembershipBuy
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/membership/history .............................................. dashboard.membership.history
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/message ................................... dashboard.message › App\Livewire\Dashboard\Message
  GET|HEAD  dashboard/support .................................................................... dashboard.support
  POST      delete-preview .......................................................... UploadController@deletePreview
  POST      email/verification-notification . verification.send › Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController@store
  POST      filter ................................................................. filter › FilterController@index
  GET|HEAD  forgot-password ............................. password.request › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@create
  POST      forgot-password ................................ password.email › Auth\PasswordResetLinkController@store
  POST      get-option .................................................................... ToolController@getOption
  POST      image/upload .......................................................... upload › UploadController@upload
  POST      increment-when-click ................................................. ToolController@incrementWhenClick
  GET|HEAD  livewire/livewire.js ....................... Livewire\Mechanisms › FrontendAssets@returnJavaScriptAsFile
  GET|HEAD  livewire/preview-file/{filename} livewire.preview-file › Livewire\Features › FilePreviewController@hand…
  POST      livewire/update .................... livewire.update › Livewire\Mechanisms › HandleRequests@handleUpdate
  POST      livewire/upload-file ............ livewire.upload-file › Livewire\Features › FileUploadController@handle
  POST      load-sub-property-filter ........................................ FilterController@loadSubPropertyFilter
  GET|HEAD  login ............................................... login › Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@create
  POST      login ........................................................ Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@store
  GET|HEAD  login/google/callback ..................................... callback › Auth\SocialiteController@callback
  GET|HEAD  login/google/redirect ..................................... redirect › Auth\SocialiteController@redirect
  POST      logout ........................................................ logout › Auth\SocialiteController@logout
  GET|HEAD  logout ..................................................... Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController@destroy
  PUT       password .............................................. password.update › Auth\PasswordController@update
  GET|HEAD  post ...................................................................... post › PostController@create
  POST      post .......................................................................... PostController@storeForm
  GET|HEAD  post/{category}/{sub_category?} .......................... post.create › PostController@createWithParams
  GET|HEAD  profile .......................................................... profile.edit › ProfileController@edit
  PATCH     profile ...................................................... profile.update › ProfileController@update
  DELETE    profile .................................................... profile.destroy › ProfileController@destroy
  GET|HEAD  property-in/{region} ................... home.location › CategoryPage\CategoryController@locationInRoute
  GET|HEAD  register ............................................... register › Auth\RegisteredUserController@create
  POST      register ........................................................... Auth\RegisteredUserController@store
  POST      reset-password ....................................... password.store › Auth\NewPasswordController@store
  GET|HEAD  reset-password/{token} .............................. password.reset › Auth\NewPasswordController@create
  GET|HEAD  robots ................................................................. robots › RobotsController@index
  GET|HEAD  sanctum/csrf-cookie .................. sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
  GET|HEAD  search ............................................................ home.search › SearchController@index
  GET|HEAD  sitemap .............................................................. sitemap › SitemapController@index
  POST      sort ...................................................................... sort › FilterController@sort
  GET|HEAD  verify-email .............................. verification.notice › Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController
  GET|HEAD  verify-email/{id}/{hash} .............................. verification.verify › Auth\VerifyEmailController
  GET|HEAD  view/{listing}/{slug} ............................................... home.view › ViewAdController@index
  GET|HEAD  {category} ....................................... home.category › CategoryPage\CategoryController@index
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type} ....................... home.category.type › CategoryPage\CategoryController@typeRoute
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type}/{regency}/{district} home.category.type.region.district › CategoryPage\DistrictContro…
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type}/{regency}/{district}/harga-{bottom}-sampai-{top}-{suffix}-an home.category.type.regio…
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type}/{regency}/{district}/{village} home.category.type.region.district.village › CategoryP…
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type}/{regency}/{district}/{village}/harga-{bottom}-sampai-{top}-{suffix}-an home.category.…
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type}/{region} home.category.type.region › CategoryPage\CategoryController@provinceRegencyR…
  GET|HEAD  {category}/{type}/{region}/harga-{bottom}-sampai-{top}-{suffix}-an home.category.type.region.price › Ca…

                                                                                                 Showing [76] routes
```

You could see that we have define route but when I open it, it redirect to homepage. Using global middleware by default of Laravel

```
   protected $middleware = [
            // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Route sample for contact in web.php

```
Route::get('/contact',function(){
    dd('contact');
})->name('contact');
```

Here I am just trying to use "dd" but it still redirect to the homepage but if I changed into /contact1 then it opens the "dd".

Things I have done

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: can you show where you are calling this route and may be there are other routes which will contradict with this route. please also show the routes.

Comment: Calling it directly since its from web.php and use GET method. Do you need me to show all the route list?

Comment: yes, show the routes because it is hard for us to determine what is the issue

Comment: I have shown the route, seems that it causes from the login. The file in route/auth.php could not be read. I moved to web.php and it works now. I do not modify anything anyway but dunno why this one is happening

Comment: before the auth file was included in the web ? if used auth package then they should be included in the web by default and if not laravel will not recognize the auth file as in the route service there are only two files registered web and api.

Comment: I have just put require __DIR__.'/auth.php'; seems to be missing there. It works now, thank you

Comment: you are catching everything here `GET|HEAD  {category}`, all the routes with only 1 trailing slash path that runs after that line will be ignored